# Creating CSize wrapper from QSize

Tags: qt

I am trying to create a wrapper for QSize class of Qt.
Here is the code snippet.

```
class CSize
{
private:
    QSize m_szSize;

public:
    int cx,cy;

CSize();
CSize(int cx,int cy)
{

}
CSize(const CSize& obj)
{
    m_szSize.setWidth(obj.cx);
    m_szSize.setHeight(obj.cy);
}
};
```

But when following situation arrives,

```
CSize sz;
sz.cx = 10;
sz.cy = 20;
```

How can i update the values of `m_szSize`.
Someone please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `cx` and `cy` as private, and add accessors for `cx` and `cy`:

```
void setCx(int p_cx) { cx = p_cx; m_szSize.setWidth(cx); }
void setCy(int p_cy) { cy = p_cy; m_szSize.setHeight(cy); }
int getCx() const { return cx; }
int getCy() const { return cy; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be safer to keep the data in a qsize and just create the CSize when needed.

eg if you need a csize for a call to some exisitng API

`CallToSomeOldAPI(CSize(m_qsize.x,m_qsize.y));`